# Android ORMlite: how to configure nested POJO classes?

Tags: android, annotations, nested, ormlite, pojo

I have an Android app that manages places (like museums, houses), each of them has contents associated (photos principally).

I have these POJO classes (generated from json returned by my server using [this tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)):

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "sm_objects")
public class SMObject {
    ...
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private List<SMContent> contents = new ArrayList<Contents>();
    ...
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "sm_contents")
public class SMContent {
    ...
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;
    ...
}
```

How can I configure these two classes to be correctly parsed and managed by ORMLite?
Which annotations I have to use for the list "contents"?

Thanks in advance.